# Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost=1527/books;create=true using org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

an error occurred while trying to add MySQL database file to netbeans

ERROR TEXT :
"Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost=1527/books;create=true using org.apache.derby.client.ClientAutoloadedDriver (java.net.UnknownHostException : Error connecting to server localhost=1527 on port 1,527 with message localhost=1527.)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27ALE.png)

Comment: You seem to be using a derby database driver, but you wrote you wanted to connect to mysql. If you want to connect to mysql, then you need to use a mysql driver.

Comment: Is it really `localhost=1527/` OR is it perhaps meant to be `localhost:1527/` ?

Comment: @MrR thank you it worked